# Permission Denied on a database created by the same user

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I run this command:

```
psql --username=openerp --dbname=sf_template_20150608111121 --no-password \
     --command="update pg_database set datallowconn = false \
                where datname = 'sf_template_20150608111121'"
```

I use the `openerp` user to create all my databases. However, I get this error message:

> ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_database

Why can't I access such table in my database? (again: the user is the actual creator of the database).  My aim is to fully disable connections to this database.

Comment: `pg_database` is a table, right? Not a database. Or are you trying to manually change the contents of the system catalog `pg_database`?

Comment: I tried the command I put in the question

Comment: OK. So you have a database named `sf_template_20150608111121` and you want to disallow (which user?) connecting to it?

Comment: I want to fully disallow access to the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753225/postgres-permission-denied-on-updating-pg-catalog-pg-cast , http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-roles.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html

Answer (score 1):

Although `openerp` owns the database, the catalog tables are still owned by user `postgres`. In order to update `pg_database`, you need to be logged in as `postgres`, or another superuser role.

This makes sense, given that `pg_database` contains entries not just for your database, but for every database on the server.

If you want to disable connections to a database without superuser privileges, try:

```
ALTER DATABASE sf_template_20150608111121 CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
```